# Define $f$ on $[0, 4]$ by $f(x) = x+ 1$ for $0 ≤ x < 2$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $2 ≤ x ≤ 4$. Use the extreme value theorem to show that f is not continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

> Define $f$ on $[0, 4]$ by $f(x) = x+ 1$ for $0 ≤ x < 2$ and $f(x) = 1$
>   for $2 ≤ x ≤ 4$. Use the extreme value theorem to show that f is not
>   continuous

So I'm having a little hard time doing this problem.

As I understand it, the extreme value theorem says

> $\{f:[a,b]↦ω | ω⊆ℝ Λ a,b∈ℝ\} ⇒ \{∀p|p∈[a,b]:\lim \limits_{x \to p}f(x)=f(p)⇒∃c,∃d|c,d∈[a,b] : f(c) = \sup f ∧ f(d) = \inf f\}$

So, I imagine that in order to solve this problem, I should use the converse

> $\{f:[a,b]↦ω | ω⊆ℝ Λ a,b∈ℝ\} ⇒ \{∀c,∀d|c,d∈[a,b] : f(c) ≠ \sup f ∨ f(d) ≠ \inf f ⇒ ∃p|p∈[a,b]:\lim \limits_{x \to p}f(x)≠f(p)\}$

So, if this is the graph of the function

[image]

I should prove that $f$ doesn't reach either its maximum or its minimum in $[a,b]$, and this would be a sufficient condition for $f$ not to be continuous in $[a,b].$ It's kinda' clear from the graph, but I'm having trouble proving it analytically.

What I see is that $\lim \limits_{x \to 2^{-}}f(x)=3$, so if $f(2)=3$, according to the graph, $3$ would be the maximum, but $f(2)=1$ so it never actually reaches its maximum. I could get closer and closer to $2$ in the domain and find the images of such values in the range closer and closer to $3$, but when actually reaching $2$, it wouldn't reach $3$, but $1$, thus not reaching the maximum.
However, I don't know if this reasoning is either correct or formal enough. It feels more like an intuition.

Could you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The intuition is right, but it needs to be formalized. I imagine you can use an epsilon delta proof to show that the limit of the function maxes out at three, but never reaches three.

Comment: You should show that the interval $[3, \infty)$ is not in the range of the function, which should be easy from its definition. Then, if $f(x) < 3$, find a way to define a $y$ (depending on $x$) such that $f(x) < f(y)$. This shows there cannot be a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose on the contrary that it is continuous, then by extreme value theorem, then there is a maximum.

Let's prove that $f([0,2))=[1,3)$,

Let $y \in f([0,2))$, then there $\exists x \in [0,2)$ such that $f(x)=x+1=y.$ $0 \le x < 2 \implies 1 \le y< 3.$

Conversely, if $y \in [1,3)$, then we have $y-1 \in [0,2)$ and we have $f(y-1) =y$. Hence $y \in f([0,2)$.

$$f([0,4])=f([0,2))\cup f([2,4])=[1,3) \cup \{1\}=[1,3)$$

and it doesn't have a maximum value.